# Make Meyers' Singleton thread safe and fast with lazy evaluation

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton

So i read a lot about *why* this implementation isn't thread-safe. But I didn't find the answer how to make it thread safe and fast? The variant of make it thread safe is to add mutex(or in some cases just critical section will be enough), but it will make this method much more slower. So is there a variant to make this code thread safe and fast, or at least now as slow as adding mutex there?

```
static Singleton& getInstance()
{
     static Singleton singleton;
     return singleton;
}
```

PS: and yes, I also read a lot about thread safe Singletom implementation when we use Singleton pointer as a member of the class, the question is about this particular implementation of Singleton, without pointers and new and using lazy evaluation.

Comment: Here's a hint: the implementation problems you're running into are probably an indication that what you're trying to do is wrong.

Comment: Why not just use a global var instead of a singleton?

Comment: @DeadMG I think that most probably what I am asking is impossible, but I'm not sure, so I'm asking =)

Comment: Fast, thread-safe, lazy - pick any two.

Comment: Make you thingy class thread-safe.  Just construct one instance of thingy in your startup code.   Do it just once.  Don't make any more thingies ever.  Instant singleton.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So seems the answer to my question best expressed Fred Larson in his comment:

"Fast, thread-safe, lazy - pick any two."

Answer (score 2):

For some compilers what you have may already have a threadsafe guarantee. If you don't care about code portability and it works for you, then be happy with it.

If you have boost thread available you can use `boost::call_once` to initialise. This is threadsafe and only costs on first initialisation.

You can of course also make a "Meyers" singleton creation totally thread-safe by initialising it, i.e. accessing it the first time, before you create threads that access it. If you have lots of these singletons already implemented consider doing that.

All of these, even `boost::call_once` only applies to the creation of the object. Its access, however, may need separate synchronisation techniques if accessed by multiple threads.

(Incidentally Item 47 of Meyers Effective C++ where this singleton is mentioned suggests that later revisions of the standard made it thread-safe and later compilers conformed with it, however it does warn you that not all compilers are compliant yet).

Comment: Yes, the big downside of the Meyers singleton is non-deterministic destruction order of these objects so if any depend on any others, you can't guarantee which one goes first which could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you can't do it without a mutex at all, but you can make that mutex fast.

First declare a class to hold the mutex, and a ready flag (`InitMutex` below).  When `GrabMutex()` is called and `ready` is `false`, the actual mutex is grabbed.  When `ReleaseMutex()` is called it does the right thing based on the flag sent from `GrabMutex()`.  After the first time through, ready goes true as the static object is now initialized, so the mutex doesn't need to be grabbed.

Now, declare a class which calls `GrabMutex()` in the constructor and `ReleaseMutex(flag)` in the destructor, saving the flag locally (`InitMutexHolder` below).

Now, instantiate that class inside your regular `getSingleton` function.  This will ensure that the singleton initialization is mutexed the first time through, and if multiple threads contend they will line up on the mutex.  But once the singleton is initialized, `ready` goes true, and access will be fast.  The destructor is called magically after `return theSingleton` is executed, which releases the mutex (or does nothing if the mutex was not taken).

But, the main body of code in your `theSingleton()` function is unchanged, we have only added a control object per singleton, and a stack object in the call which manages the thread safety.

Note about write barriers: since the code is safe whenever `ready` is false, and `ready` can't go true until the object is initialized, the code is overall safe assuming that writes are instantly visible.  But, there may be a delay in `ready=true` being visible, since there is no write barrier after setting ready true.  However, during that delay safety is still maintained, since `ready=false` is the conservative, safe case.

```
class InitMutex
{
public:
   InitMutex() : ready(false) { }

   bool  GrabMutex()
   {
      if (!ready)
      {
         mutex.Grab();
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   void ReleaseMutex(bool flagFromGrabMutex)
   {
      if (flagFromGrabMutex)
      {
          mutex.Release();
          ready = true;
      }
   }

   Mutex   mutex;
   bool    ready;
};

class InitMutexHolder
{
public:
    InitMutexHolder(InitMutex & m)
    : initMutex(m)
    {
       inMutex = initMutex.GrabMutex();
    }
    ~InitMutexHolder()
    {
       initMutex.ReleaseMutex(inMutex);
    }

private:
    bool inMutex;
    InitMutex & initMutex;
};

static InitMutex singletonMutex;
static Singleton & getSingleton()
{
    InitMutexHolder mutexHolder(singletonMutex);
    {
       static Singleton theSingleton;
       return theSingleton;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think I forget to add into the topic words "lazy evaluations", sorry.

Comment: I clearly understand that Singleton is initialized only once, and that initialize it before main will be thread safe, but it won't be lazy evaluation.

Comment: I know that variant that you wrote now. It is stated in my question in the PS that I'm asking about realization without new and pointers. I guessed before asked my question that the answer is "no, it's not possible", and your post seems to answers the same )

Comment: just because without *new* I don't need to care about *delete* :-) As far as I understand when using Singleton implementation with pointer and new inside getInstance method we are counting that somewhere outside the Sigleton class delete will be called, and it's seems like a huge probability of having memory leak.

Comment: OK I have an answer - completely rewriting this :)